# Make a video editor with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, video-processing

Im Trying To Automate Boring EveryDay Tasks,But I Need Your Help!
What i  need to do i:

```
1.Send A Video File From My Ipad To Get Proccesed
2.Procces The Video(Just Putting Some Textoverlays,and resizing the frame)
3.Return The Video To My Ipad
```

I Want To Do Most Of This With Python3
If i could send the data through a web server maybe?
So can anyone help?
I just need some references on what i can do,no need to fully code this for me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the step `2` - I did something similar using `opencv` before. This [tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file) is a good starting point.

The step `1` and `3` can get quite complicated depending on your setup. One way that comes to my mind is using AWS S3. You can upload to an S3 bucket from the iPad and download it from the computer where you'll run your Python script.

Comment: hey i already know how to use opencv,but with opencv the colors get messed up.

Comment: ill try it again :)